# Permission denied when reading/writing contacts no syntax errors

Tags: android

All, I seem to be receiving a security permission error even though my manifest appears to be properly formatted, and the syntax is correct when declaring permission. Ive checked several other previous posts on stackoverflow for the issue, however I have been unable to resolve it.  I am assuming it may be an issue with the emulator running the app.  I am currently using target SDK of 23.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

    <application
        android:name=".GetHashKeyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/FBAPPID" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FindContactActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ContactDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact_information"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Exception**

```
10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{a99c081 5182:com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder/u0a53} (pid=5182, uid=10053) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at utils.ContactHelper.retrieveContacts(ContactHelper.java:34)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder.ContactListFragment.initializeData(ContactListFragment.java:44)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder.ContactListFragment.onCreateView(ContactListFragment.java:31)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1016)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1197)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1562)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:535)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    10-14 18:09:48.531 5182-5182/com.thundercats.ho.contactfinder E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
```

Answer (score 2):

On Android 6.0 (API 23) and targeting API 23, you use [runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) as explained in [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/building-better-apps-with-runtime.html) and the [documentation on runtime permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html).

You'll need to request permissions at runtime before being able to use dangerous permissions such as `READ_CONTACTS`.

Comment: Really help me. Save my time. Thanks @ianhanniballake.